# MySQL errors after reinstalling

Tags: linux, mysql, apt

At first, I wanted to reinstall MySQL to repair
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` problem with command `apt-get purge mysql-server`, `apt-get purge mysql-client` etc. and manually removing folders like `/var/lib/mysql/`, `/etc/mysql/` etc.

While installing fresh MySQL package with `apt-get install mysql-server`, I ran into this:

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to stop MySQL, but all I get is `Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.` Command `apt-get --fix-broken install` does not work either, due to the same problem as above.

`mysql` command works, but it results in the same problem as in the beginning.

Comment: It says that there is a MySQL server running. Are there a `mysql` process running on the machine when you check with `ps`?

Comment: @NasirRiley no, which is kinda weird for me (I've checked it with ps, htop and glances - no sight of mysql nor mysqld)

Answer (score 1):

There's **open bug** on this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-8.0/+bug/1897381

Associated: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1612517

**Fixed:**
I know this old, but here's what fixed in my case:

- Check for any broken service link (`/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service` )
- Remove any MariaDB stuff (`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep maria`)
- Details found [here](https://blog.kesavan.info/2024/03/03/fix-for-mysql-8x-installation-failure-on-ubuntu-20-04/)